# Is there a way to limit line width in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'd like my Gmail editor to enforce a maximum line width for emails I'm composing, say 70 or 80 chars.  Is there a way to do this?  Perhaps with a Chrome extension?

Comment: This is the default behavior of their native BlackBerry App.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Gmail does this automatically, but it only does it in plain-text messages. Turn off *Rich Formatting* in your message and it'll be wrapped to ~80 characters before it's sent.

Comment: Maybe at one point. Seems like it wraps at 120 now.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's any such tool out there.

Your most viable option is to use a text editor to compose your message and then paste it into a Gmail message. This might be helpful: [How can I add line breaks to a text file?](http://ask.metafilter.com/176759/How-can-I-add-line-breaks-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a browser extension that let's you define custom CSS, then add this rule:

```
.ii.gt {
  max-width: 430px;
}
```

There's a [blog post](https://medium.com/@ericandrewlewis/how-i-fixed-gmails-email-width-problem-da4e3ffd97ea) by a software engineer that details how he did it for the Chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

If you are a Firefox user you can have line wrapping and many other editing and formatting features by simply using Thunderbird as your user client. You can have that and still use gmail as your email system.  It will even provides utilities for backing up and restoring messages.  Check out elegant user-designed free software at Mozzila.org.
correte